# retrieve a user whose one column field is blank

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

How to retrieve the detail of a student whose course column field is blank?

How can this be done with a query?

Comment: table name Student...column name "course" 
one student course column field is blank,,,,, how to retrieve this studnet detail with the help of a query

Comment: best to include the datatype of the column for the best answer. We've assumed your column's datatype is a `varchar`. If it's a numeric datatype, then the answer would be different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Student
WHERE course = ''
OR course IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from the question whether a null entry qualifies a row as part of the resultset.

Try this:

```
SELECT * From Student 
WHERE Course = '' 
OR Course IS NULL  --remove/keep this depending on your need for null checking
```